# SharePoint 2013 community site - Discussion list calendar view missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, community-site

I have a SharePoint online intranet portal in Office 365 and I have created a discussions list. I tried to create a calendar view but noticed that this option is missing. Am I missing something or the OOTB discussions list doesn't have calendar view feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion board does not have a calendar view available. I don't recall it ever having an option to use a calendar view in any version of SharePoint.